# Boot desktop PC from SSD installed in Laptop over ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, boot, laptop

For work I mainly use a Laptop (OS is Ubuntu 20.04), because I need to be mobile. However, when I am at home I also have a powerful desktop PC (also running Ubuntu 20.04) which I prefer to use to compile large software projects, as it is much faster.
Since I often switch between Laptop and PC I need to keep all my files synchronized (documents, browser bookmarks, etc.) which is of course possible, but I would like to achieve a more comfortable solution.

Would it be possible, to not use the SSD installed in the PC at all, but boot from the SSD installed in the laptop instead directly? For example with boot over ethernet? Then I could use the computing power of the PC and when I need to take my laptop with me I don't need to remember synchronizing it, because I use the same SSD anyways.

My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad T14s AMD (1Gbit ethernet) and the desktop PC is an AM4 platform with 2.5GBit ethernet adapter.

I am happy to provide more details if necessary. Not sure if what I would like to achieve is possible at all. I am willing to buy additional hardware if needed (e.g. a switch?).

Comment: In theory you could use [netboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_booting). In practise it would be so cripplingly slow you wouldn't try it twice.

Comment: Is there so much overhead for the ethernet connection? I thought that 1GBit/s transfer rate might be sufficient to work without stutters. And the compilation is CPU and not I/O limited

Comment: Why not use RDP to access the desktop from the laptop?

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation, thank you for your question!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but remember that standard Gigabit Ethernet is just ~100 MB/s, which is far slower than any SSD (even SATA SSDs work at ~500 MB/s) and for large linear reads it's slower than even most HDDs. It may be the most similar to booting from a cheap USB stick.

For daily work (interactive usage), this might actually negate the performance gains you get from the faster CPU. You will most likely need to compile software on local storage or a tmpfs (in-memory), otherwise the network filesystem won't be able to keep up. Remember that in order to compile a file, the compiler actually has to *read* it first (and then read the included headers, and their included headers, and...) – even with caching it will still introduce a significant delay before actually reaching the CPU-bound process.

Besides that, I would still recommend booting the desktop OS locally, and only mounting `/home` over the network. This has several advantages:

- The boot process will be simpler. You won't need to integrate networking into the Linux initramfs – you'll be able to just use whatever is installed on the desktop normally. With NFS, this could be as simple as an /etc/fstab entry.
- The laptop's OS will not need to care about the differences in hardware between the two computers. You won't need to keep two sets of Ethernet configurations, two sets of GPU drivers, and so on.
- You will still be able to use the desktop's fast local storage for the OS itself (which avoids a considerable increase in latency in daily tasks, and leaves the Ethernet connection unoccupied – making it faster to access /home over the net).
- All network-boot mechanisms will require the laptop to be powered on the whole time and running an OS to actually serve the data.

  If you share the *entire* SSD, then you will have some trouble booting the same rootfs from two computers at once – block-based methods (iSCSI, NBD) are right out, and file-based methods (NFS, SMB) will only work reliably as long as the 2nd computer is accessing the filesystem read-only.

  For that reason, even if some admins *do* boot many systems from a central host, typically only /usr and /lib are actually shared (and importantly, read-only) while /var is still mounted from local storage.

  The only other workaround would be to boot the laptop *from a USB stick* containing a minimal "server" Linux build, which then allows it to serve the SSD in read-write mode over the network.

For system-wide mounts I would recommend starting with NFSv4, which is generally the protocol of choice for transparent Linux-to-Linux file access (practically the Unix equivalent of Windows' SMBv3).

- But keep in mind that NFS does not have a good "middle ground" security layer – it has only two options: `sec=krb5p/krb5i` (Kerberos) and `sec=sys` (trusted IP address). **The default is sec=sys**, which gives you no security whatsoever. (I have configured Kerberos for my personal servers, but it takes a little more infrastructure.)
- On Debian (and probably Ubuntu) the NFS service is available by installing `nfs-kernel-server`. Add an entry for /home to the `/etc/exports` file and make sure the firewall allows connections to port 2049/tcp. (You can ignore portmapper/statd/mountd, they're not relevant for NFSv4.)

  (Also, although some articles suggest that NFSv4 makes /etc/exports more complex with needing a magic "fsid=0" and having to put everything under "/export", that is not actually true – it's an option but the traditional way of just having /home entry is completely enough.)
- On the desktop, install `nfs-common` and try your luck with:

  ```
  mount -t nfs -o vers=4,soft,nodev,nosuid LAPTOP_ADDRESS:/home /mnt/laptop
  ```

  After it works, add an equivalent /etc/fstab entry:

  ```
  LAPTOP_ADDRESS:/home  /mnt/laptop  nfs  vers=4,soft,nodev,nosuid  0  0
  ```

  This doesn't overlay your desktop's /home. If you want that, just edit the mount path acccordingly – but if you want to have both "standalone desktop" and "tethered to laptop" options easily available then it might be easier to just keep it at /mnt/laptop.

  (The 'autofs' daemon may be used to implement more complex logic about what to mount where.)

Several alternatives are:

- `sshfs`, i.e. SFTP (SSHv2). This provides good security, the performance is *okay*, but it is restricted to one UID per mount and isn't guaranteed to support some of the rarer file operations (fallocate, truncate, etc), only basic read/write. So you can use it to access your personal home directory, but you cannot run a whole OS from it, and shouldn't be compiling much via sshfs either.
- SMBv3 (with Samba on the laptop). This provides average security, and in general ranks somewhere between SFTP and NFSv4. Doesn't do symlinks.
- `cifs` aka SMBv1 (again with Samba). No data encryption, but it does support symlinks and other POSIX-y stuff, so it could in theory be used for booting the entire OS, but wouldn't recommend.
- NBD, iSCSI and AoE (ATA-over-Ethernet). All three are used for exporting whole *block devices* (i.e. raw disks or partitions) rather than filesystems. They demand exclusive access to the device to be shared, i.e. the same /home cannot be mounted on the laptop at the same time. Also, I'm not sure whether the performance is as good as with NFS.

  So if you want to boot a whole OS over NBD/iSCSI, you can do that but the laptop needs to be running a dedicated server OS from some other medium.
- Finally, for documents I would simply use Syncthing.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for that elaborate answer. I did not think about just mounting `/home` which sounds like a good solution for me. I will try to set that up and see if I can manage to get it working.

Comment: SMBv1 should never be recommended as it's actively exploited daily and there isn't a way to secure it. All systems that support SMBv1 also support SMBv2, the minimum that should be used.

Comment: @JW0914: I think you are confusing protocols and implementations. SMBv1 is not being "actively exploited" – the Windows in-kernel server implementation of SMBv1 is. (Microsoft's IIS used to be exploited a lot, nobody said HTTP is to be avoided. Sendmail, Exim used to be exploited a lot, nobody said SMTP is to be avoided.)

Comment: @user1686 SMBv1 vulnerabilities were exploited on machines using Linux as well _(one of the more famous examples was spying that was done via smartTVs using an SMBv1 exploit)_. I may be confusing protocols and implementations, however there are zero benefits to using SMBv1 over SMBv2 and a lot of downsides, including data security since SMBv1 doesn't support encryption.

Comment: I already specified the benefit: CIFS/SMBv1 has Unix extensions (symlinks, POSIX stat/chmod, special files) and the newer versions do not. The SMBv3 POSIX extensions are still only slowly being added to Linux this year, and even with those in place, they will deliberately not be transparent (i.e. creating a symlink via SMB won't create a real symlink on disk).